# QString::replace(const QRegExp &, const QString &) and QString::replace(const QRegularExpression &, const QString &) work differently

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Why with Qt 5.1.0 Release Candidate the function QString::replace(const QRegExp & rx, const QString & after) treats the \v in a manner and QString::replace(const QRegularExpression & re, const QString & after) in another way?
That’s the peace of code that I used:

```
QString ss("a\t\v  bc \t cdef\vg\r\r\t hi");
QString ss1(ss);
ss1.replace(QRegExp("\\s{2,}"), " ");
QString ss2(ss);
ss2.replace(QRegularExpression("\\s{2,}"), " ");
```

The values with debugger are:

```
ss  "a\t\013  bc \t cdef\013g\r\r\t hi"
ss1 "a bc cdef\013g hi"
ss2 "a\t\013 bc cdef\013g hi"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QRegExp uses the Unicode "separator" category for `\s`. This includes `\v`.

QRegularExpression is a wrapper around PCRE, where the documentation states (http://pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> For  compatibility  with Perl, \s does not match the VT character
>   (code
>          11).  This makes it different from the the POSIX "space" class. The  \s
>          characters  are  HT  (9), LF (10), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32). If
>          "use locale;" is included in a Perl script, \s may match the VT charac-
>          ter. In PCRE, it never does.

Although the documentation says it never matches `\v`, you could try passing the `UseUnicodePropertiesOption` option to the QRegularExpression, which changes the character classes to use the Unicode properties, so in theory, unless a specific exception is built into PCRE, `\s` should match `\v`.

Failing that, you can use `(\h|\v)` (in C++ string form that's `"(\\h|\\v)"`), using PCRE's special "horizontal space" and "vertical space" classes.